# Http file upload fails if you idle too long after loading the page (asp.net mvc)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

So, this one is weird.

I have this page that has an upload control in it. Page loads you choose a file and the upload goes ok, all time every time.

Except when you wait two minutes after the page load, (so do nothing 2 minutes) then the upload will always fail.

I've started a client network trace and one thing I noticed is that the server response suddenly is a 401 from a Microsoft-HTTPAPI-2.0, instead of IIS:

[image: Network trace]

The authentication is set to Windows Authentication  (in IIS 8.0)

This only happens in IE (11), Chrome does not seem to have this problem, so I guess it's client side.

Comment: could this be a Session TimeOut issue / Setting version of IIS that you are using..?

Comment: Could be, but why is there no problem with Chrome then..

Comment: IE and Chrome do not act the same especially in regards rendering, extensions etc.. do not think that just because something functions correctly in one platform or environment that it's expected to do the same especially when dealing with `MicroSuck`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up calling a dummy controller method every 10 seconds from the client. This seem to have solved the problem for me.